# Guardar Datos de un formulario en una hoja de calculo de Google

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Alguien que me pueda guiar para poder configurar una hoja de calculo de google para guardar los datos que voy a capturar desde un formulario web.

Comment: Checa [ask] por favor

Comment: Bienvenido. Las preguntas en este sitio deben ser específicas, incluir una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado. Puedes empezar por buscar acerca de Google Sheets API y Google Apps Script (en este último te puedes hacer el formulario y te podría ahorra el tener que crear un proyecto de Google Cloud estándar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello te debes configurar y crear una  **[Google Sheet API.](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)** Deberás instalar la librería de Google Client Library con el siguiente comando en consola:

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

Y ya luego miras la documentación que te dirá como usarla.
Espero que te sirva :)